# Fazer uma query e ver numa dropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dropdown

Está dar o erro abaixo na dropdowList e não percebo porquê.

Erro:

> Não é possível associar o objecto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousType82[System.Int32,System.Stri‌​ng]]' ao tipo 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
>   Controlador:

```
public ActionResult CriarInscricao()
        {
            var queryNomeCatequizando = ( from c in db.Catequizando
                                          join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequizandoID equals p.PessoaID
                                          where c.CatequizandoID == p.PessoaID
                                          select new { PessoaID = p.PessoaID,  Nome = p.Nome});

            ViewBag.Catequizando = queryNomeCatequizando.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CatequizandoID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Catequizando, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Que erro está dando?

Comment: "Não é possível associar o objecto de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[System.Int32,System.String]]' ao tipo 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewBag.Catequizando` não é uma `SelectList`. É uma lista normal. Você precisa converter pra funcionar. Tem duas formas de fazer:

Primeira forma, em *Controller*:

```
ViewBag.Catequizando = new SelectList(queryNomeCatequizando, "CatequizandoID", "Nome");
```

Segunda forma, em *View*:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CatequizandoID, ((IEnumerable<CatequizandoViewModel>)ViewBag.Catequizando).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = option.Nome,
    Value = option.CatequizandoID.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.CatequizandoID == option.CatequizandoID)
}), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Na segunda forma, é preciso criar `CatequizandoViewModel` antes.